# How to fetch the Json data using retrofit 2 with Rxjava 2

Tags: java, android, json, retrofit2

I am trying to fetch the JSON data using retrofit 2. but I am unable to fetch the JSONArray. can anyone please tell me how to fetch the categories from the below json.

```
 "template": "",
"format": "standard",
"meta": [],
"categories": [
  142
],
"tags": [],
```

Code i used here to fetch the data is

```
int categories = postitemsList1.get(i).getCategories();
```

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to fetch the `int` array and trying to assign it to an `int` variable.

The right way is to create an `Integer` array and assign to it:

```
List<Integer> categories = postitemsList1.get(i).getCategories();
```

Also, it would be more helpful if you share the error stacktrace to understand the exact issue you face.

Answer (score 0):

Create the following class :

```
Class Mydata {
    @SerializedName("template") String template;
    @SerializedName("format") String format;
    @SerializedName("meta") List<Object> meta;
    @SerializedName("categories") List<Integer> categories;
    @SerializedName("tags") List<Object> tags;

    // getter/setter
}
```

Then you should have a service like this one :

```
public interface MyService {
  @GET("uri")
  Call<MyData> getMyData();
}
```

Finally create a `MyService` instance from a `Retrofit` object and call `service.getMyData()`.

For more information go to the [official website](http://square.github.io/retrofit/).